# How can I get user's walking direction using sensor fusion?

Tags: android, accelerometer, magnetometer

I am working on an Android app and I am trying to figure out how can I combine accelerometer and magnetometer to find the walking direction of the user when indoors. I understand that I can only get an approximate direction and not the real value. :)

Any ideas? Would gyroscope also help in this case?

Thanks

Comment: This will be inaccurate at best. I guess it's better to use location services (unless you are indoor).

Comment: @Henry I just need an approximate estimation. I am referring to indoor cases.

Answer (score 1):

The user's acceleration is nearly zero most of the time, therefore, walking will produce a predictable pattern. This general property serves as something like an anchor point, from which other stages of the walk can be analyzed.

With this in mind, i think a position classifier to detect where the phone is located on the body is needed. After that you can measure the angle between the phone position and the magnetic north of the earth.

But be aware, for an accurate measure, it will need an enormous filtering.

Answer (score 0):

don't know what kind of direction you mean but might possible SensorEvent helps you what your are looking. SensorEventListener is being used to build compass app. 
  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html

Comment: I need to know the direction that the user is heading to. I believe that no sensor when used alone can provide this information.